# OpenNMS passive nodes logs scanning

Tags: opennms

I would like to setup OpenNMS monitoring system where OpenNMS server will do all the job because I cannot modify nodes which must be scanned. I can although ssh and ftp to those nodes.
I am thinking about using some plugin which will ssh and tail logs.
Any suggestions for plugin I could use or good tutorial how to write my own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Opennms is at it's best when you have snmp access to your nodes.  Snmp will give you the ability to monitor, collect and graph, and without it I believe you will need to create a custom collector in order to collect and graph useful information, if that is your aim.  There are some standard collectors:
http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Docu-overview#Data_Collection

http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Documentation:Features_DataCollection

With regards to generic approaches to collecting data, you could use expect scripts  Alternatively, you could write some scripts on the clients (if you have the relevant access) that collect data which could be retrieved by the server.  You can use key-based SSH connections to ease the auth burden as long as you look after your keys.